# How can I find record in SQL that matches the start of a string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have a table of prefixes like so:

```
 Primary Key | Value

      1      | 0012
      2      | 0013
      3      | 0014
      4      | 0015
```

And wondered how I could write a query that would return the primary key of the prefix of the code I pass through.

For example if I had the value `00135648954` I would like to pass that through to a query to return `2` because `00135648954` starts with `0013`.

I have tried writing a few `LIKE` queries without success.

I looked into a `CONTAIN` query which wouldn't run because the table is not full-text indexed (also i haven't had any experience with CONTAINS so I didn't want to try too much)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `like`:

```
select primary_key
from mytable 
where @myval like concat(value, '%')
```

Where `@myval` represents the value for which you want to get the primary key.

If you want something that is null-safe (ie, that will not match if `@myval` is null), then you can use `+` as concatenation operator instead:

```
select primary_key
from mytable 
where @myval like value + '%'
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, I was so close with the queries I had tried as well!

Answer (score 0):

```
select id
from your_table
where @parameter like value + '%'
```